# Set and get loop of data by putting into list in java

Tags: java

i have for loop where i get data to send to other method in different class

UserManagerImpl.java

```
for (User user: userList) {
                surveyModel survey = new SurveyModel();
                survey.setSurveyData(Id, comment, serveyScore, grade);
            }
```

In other class i have set and get to create list of datas and then want to fetch it by get method.

surveyModel.java

```
public class SurveySentimentModel {
    public static String delimiter = "|||"; 
    private List scores = new ArrayList();
    private List negativeData = new ArrayList();
    private List PositiveData = new ArrayList();


    public void setSurveyData(String Id, String comment, double Score, String grade) {
        //want to add score to scores list
        //if grade positive add to positive list or else negative after delimiting  
    }
        public double getTotalScore() {
        //calculate the sum of scores
        return totalScore;
    }


public String getTotalSentimentgrade() {
        if (totalScore> 0) {
            return "Positive";
        }
        return "Negative";
    }

    public List getSurveyData() {
        //Want to merge list - first negative and then positive
        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

SurveyModel.java

```
private String grade;
private Number Score;
private String Id;
private String comment;

public SurveyModel(String Id, String comment, double Score, String grade) {
    this.grade= grade;
    this.Score= Score;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.Id = Id;
}
public SurveyModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

// getters and setters

IN here i want to

```
1.) Add score to scores list 
2.) want to add graddes to list by negative first with delimiter then positive.
3.) want to get total score.
```

How could i achive my requirement. I am new to java please help me on this.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Bill F  The given layout idea , put in query is done my me. But not know how to achieve it by putting into list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

This is the Model class:

```
    public class SurveySentimentModel {
        public static String delimiter = "|||"; 
        private List<SurveyModel> scores = new ArrayList();
        private List<SurveyModel> negativeData = new ArrayList();
        private List<SurveyModel> positiveData = new ArrayList();


        public void setSurveyData(String Id, String comment, double score, String grade) {
            SurveyModel survey =  new SurveyModel(id, comment, score, grade );
            scores.add(survey)
            if(score >= 0){
              positiveData.add(survey);
            }else{
              negativeData.add(survey);
            }
        }
        public double getTotalScore() {
            double sum = 0;
            for(SurveyModel s: scores){
                sum += s.getScore();
            }
            return sum;
        }
        public List getSurveyData() {
            List<SurveyModel> joined = new ArrayList(negativeData);
            joined.addAll(positiveData)
            return joined;
        }
    }
```

This is the loop:

```
SurveySentimentModel sentiments = new SurveySentimentModel();
for (User user: userList) {
      sentiments.setSurveyData(user.getId(), user.getComment(), user.getSurveryScore(), user.getGrade());
}
```

Comment: Here are three things i am not getting as you suggested 1.)i am not able to use scores.stream().mapToDouble(SurveyModel::getScore).sum(); it shows error in this line(i am using java 7). 2.) i am not able to get list as return in getsurveyData, because of addall(positiveData), this force it to change return type to boolean. 3.)i want to add delimiter before positiveData list at first time.

Comment: stream is java 8+

Comment: I changed it to a Java7 compatible loop. I dont understand what you mean by delimiter before positiveData.

Comment: @Raphael.I have added one more arraylist(), i am merging three list, in getsurveyData by this   List<SurveyModel> mergedSurveyDataList = new ArrayList();
   mergedSurveyDataList.addAll(negativeData);
   mergedSurveyDataList.addAll(nuetralData);
   mergedSurveyDataList.addAll(positiveData); but by this each time list size gets d0ubles. How to get only unique list elemnts